# If there a snippet I'm missing in Tumblr to specify every-other?

Tags: tumblr

I'm hoping there are some Tumblr pro's out there today.

Just wondering if there is a Tumblr template snippet that executes on every other post?

Basically something like this:

```
{block:Pages}
<ul>
  <li><a href="" {switch}class="odd"{/switch}></a>
</ul>
{/block:Pages}
```

Just trying to add that extra class on odd posts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got 2 options:

The first would be to trigger every odd/even post entry by using `{block:Odd} {/block:Odd}`

Alternatively, you could use `{Alt}` in conversation posts.

As for something that works like {Alt} in every single post, I'm not aware of any and you'll have to use the Tumblr API along with JSON to manipulate it.

Hope it helps :)